# How to include SASS files using sass-rails gem with the Asset Pipeline in Rails 3.2.15? Operation not supported?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm trying to figure out the best practise way to serve my (SASS) CSS assets. I've googled and googled and now my mind is boggled!

Rails 3.2.15

**Gemfile:**

```
# Asset pipeline
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.6'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier',     '2.3.0'
end
```

**production.rb**

```
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )

  # Choose which compressors to use
  # config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :scss
```

**application.css.scss**

```
/*
*= require data_tables
*= require data_tables_colvis
*= require styles
*= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
*= require jquery.ui.datepicker
*= require jquery.ui.slider
*= require timepicker
*= stub email
*= require_directory
*/

.ui-widget,
.ui-widget input,
.ui-widget select,
.ui-widget textarea,
.ui-widget button { font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit; }
```

Note, some of the files i `require` are in `app/assets/stylesheets` while others are in `vendor/assets/stylesheets`

**Commands run**

```
rm -rf tmp/
rm -rf public/assets/
bundle exec rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=production --trace
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace
```

**Error encountered**

```
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Operation not supported - (/media/shared/code/user/appname/tmp/cache/sass/21e55874b33b09754ee1326254c109e623619141/application.css.scssc20131108-41651-yzw3cr, /media/shared/code/user/appname/tmp/cache/sass/21e55874b33b09754ee1326254c109e623619141/application.css.scssc)
  (in /media/shared/code/user/appname/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/util.rb:886:in `rename'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/util.rb:886:in `atomic_create_and_write_file'
```

The trailing `c` on the temp file path seems slightly suspicious to me?

Any ideas what's going on? What is the 'right' way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: According to one of your commands above, you removed the tmp directory. You might need to `mkdir tmp/cache`.

Comment: Thanks for the response but i just tried creating the folder and get the same error message :(

Comment: It's erroring out when trying to rename a file. Can the deployment user write to the tmp directory? Does the sass directory get created? Also, the trailing `c` you're seeing in the name should be the compiled version of the sass css.

Comment: Yes, as it should be running as me. I also tried `sudo` for good measure but no dice. Yes `tmp/cache/sass` is created and so is the subfolder, but nothing is inside it. Of note, if i downgrade to sass-rails 3.2.5 - everything seems to work?

Comment: Good call reverting back to 3.2.5. Based on [this commit](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/commit/bdfeb7ba71eae9ab0b214190319e109bbb0a9fe7) it looks like they changed the default sass style to `:compressed`. You might try adding `config.sass.style = :nested` or `config.sass.style = :expanded` to `production.rb` and try 3.2.6 again.

Comment: I tried setting all three available options (`:compressed`, `:nested` and `:expanded`) in `config/environments/production.rb` with 3.2.6 but still got the same error. I did also try setting `config.sass.cache = false` and that seems to have maybe by completely avoiding the underlying issue... Not a satisfying resolution (and compiling became unbearably slow) :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting back to `sass-rails` v3.2.5 appeared to fix the problem.